# jQuery slideshow appearance issue in older versions of IE

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have come across an issue that I cannot see for myself. A client of ours sent me a screenshot of their website homepage which uses a jquery content slider. Photos fade in and out with a `div` on top that displays text. Apparently the text divs are piling up on top of each other. I have viewed it on Mac and PC browsers but could never see the issue. The screenshot however, proves it (sorry, not able to post the image). I cannot access any earlier version of IE and I suspect that's the culprit. I am asking anyone out there that has an emulator or any ideas of why this may be happening for your help. The url is [kokuaservices.com](http://kokuaservices.com)

Thanks.

Comment: You can access older verisons of IE by using [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

Comment: cool Spudley but I'm on a Mac at my workstation and Firefox add-ons I've found are horrible.

Comment: have you tried browser agent switching addon for ff? easily change to ie6, 7 etc..

Answer (score 0):

You've got some code errors that might be causing the IE problems: [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  kokuaservices.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//kokuaservices.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

And you should find a Windows box to test in native windows for best results, as you're loading a lof of JS.

Your slider images are also way too big, file-size. Total page weight is over 3 megs.

Comment: Thanks songdogtech! Don't know why I didn't validate this in the first place... ever since we started creating Wordpress sites I have skipped that step in the end process. Time to start checking again :) What do you mean about the Windows box to text?

Comment: That was a typo - I meant test. You should find a windows PC to test the site, as IE emulators are problematic.